# Using different databases for Debug and Release on Entity Framework Code First (DbContext)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext, localdb

I've created the app database using [MSDN Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx), but now i'm struggling trying to have 2 separate databases, one for when i'm debugging and another for releases, because it doesn't add any app.config line for the connection string...

When i open the properties for the database at server explorer i can see that the actual connection string is `Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MediaManager.Model.Context;Integrated Security=True`, but i can't differentiate it when in debug or release mode...

How can i do it?

---

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MediaManager.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MediaManager.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <userSettings>
    <MediaManager.Properties.Settings>
      ...
    </MediaManager.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
  <applicationSettings>
    <MediaManager.Properties.Settings>
      ...
    </MediaManager.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

---

**Context.cs**

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MediaManager.Model
{
    public class Context : DbContext, IContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Episodio> Episodio { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Serie> Serie { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<SerieAlias> SerieAlias { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Feed> Feed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just have 2 different strings in app.config file and use #if DEBUG to set your connection strings?

Comment: Environments has to be set by development, staging and production. Not sure which version of MVC you are using, but it is possible as per this link[http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html]

Comment: @anoop - As proven by me just clicking the link - hot linking is totally useless, (link now dead) please put the answer into the comments or provide an answer in future..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply update your `Context` to pass in the name of a connection string, and define this connection string in your `web.config`.

For example:

```
public class Context : DbContext, IContext
{
    public Context() : base("MyContext") { }

    public virtual DbSet<Episodio> Episodio { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Serie> Serie { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<SerieAlias> SerieAlias { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Feed> Feed { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `web.config`

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyContext" connectionString="..your connection string.." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Once this is in place, you can then use [Web Configuration Transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) to automatically update the connection string for a **Release** build vs. a **Debug** build.